# Why does this javascript sleep function skip immediately?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Where isPaused becomes true, the sleep function should go into an infinite loop right??? but for some reason it does not, instead it will print "here2" immediately after? i am using this with an async function which when it is done the bool isPaused becomes false again.

```
var isPaused = false;

function sleep() {
    if (isPaused == true) {
        setTimeout(function(){sleep()},1000);
    }
};

console.log("here");

isPaused = true;

sleep();

console.log("here 2");
```

how can i fix it so it will wait, instead of continuing.

Comment: http://latentflip.com/loupe/ use this website to visualise how the code is called.

Comment: It is going into infinite loop

Comment: The timer is going in an infinite loop as xMayank stated, but code can run while a timer is active, so the `console.log("here 2");` is executed while the timer is active.

Comment: @DaemonBeast how do i get it to not run the next line and stay in the sleep until its false again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to wait for the timer, you need to use a `Promise` with `async` and `await`:

```js
(async () => {
    var isPaused = false;
    
    setTimeout(function() {
        isPaused = false;
    }, 3000);

    async function sleep() {
        if (isPaused == true) {
            await new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(async function() {
                    await sleep();
                    resolve()
                }, 1000);
            });
        }
        
        return;
    }

    console.log("here");

    isPaused = true;

    await sleep();

    console.log("here 2");
})();
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zeraora/t4o8qr2x/).

Answer (score 1):

Your code will run the sleep function, then run it again after 1000 milliseconds.

What your code does:

1. Set isPaused to false
2. Define the sleep function (not execute it)
3. log "here"
4. Set isPaused to true
5. Execute the sleep function, it will be called again after 1000ms, but the program doesn't wait for this, so it already executes the next line.
6. log "here 2"

Comment: Depends what you want to do. Do you want your program to stop for 1000ms, then continue?

Comment: yeh i want it to stop and wait, then continue on instead of continuing and and outputting what ever is in that loop until its false again

Answer (score 0):

Because the function sleep is done setting the timeout, so the code can then continue the rest of the operations.

Then after having continued operations for 1s (1000ms) it will perform another sleep, after which it is free to run any other potentially remaining operations.

So the infinite loop does happen, it just doesn't prohibit other code from running.
Try putting a console.log('test') in the first line of the sleep function.

```
function sleep() {
    console.log("test")
    if (isPaused == true) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            sleep()
        },1000);
    }
};
```

A little too much to get into here, and others can explain a lot better than me, but look into the JS Event Loop, that should clarify some things!

Answer (score 0):

That's already an infinite loop. Just try to add an "console.log('loop')" inside the setTimeout function and you will see how it's called each second.

Also, remember javascript is not syncronous, so it will print here 2 before the sleep (remember, it requires 1 sec), but it keep working in the infinite loop